# different color in one UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

this is what I am trying to do. I have a UILabel, but one word in that UILabel should be in a red color. After some research I found the [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)
But I can't get my head arround it. Because my label is multilanguage so it's quite difficult because they are all working with NSRange.

Here is my label.

```
In dutch:
      Het 25m bad is vandaag **bezet** van 12:00 tot 15:00
In English
      The 25m pool is today **occupied** from 12:00 till 15:00
```

I need the text in bold in the red color.

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Text will be dynamic?

Comment: Yes it can be occupied or bezet

Comment: You want to change the text appearance only for occupied or bezet or it may vary depending on the text?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could use this snippet to get the `NSRange` where "occupied" or "bezet" is:

```
NSRange occupiedRange = [str rangeOfString:NSLocalizedString(@"occupied", @"")];
if (occupiedRange.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Not found");
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code snippet may work for you

```
-(NSAttributedString*)configureToAttributedwithString:(NSString*)str
{
NSRange occupiedRange = [str rangeOfString:NSLocalizedString(@"occupied", @"")];
if (occupiedRange.location == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Not found");
    NSAttributedString *attRStr = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str] autorelease];

    return (attRStr);
}
else
{
    NSString *string = [str substringToIndex:occupiedRange.location];

    str = [str substringFromIndex:occupiedRange.location];

    NSString *tarGetString = [str substringToIndex:occupiedRange.length];

    str = [str substringFromIndex:occupiedRange.length];

    CGColorRef colorRed = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    NSNumber *underline = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle];
    CTFontRef sysUITargetFont = CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage(kCTFontUIFontEmphasizedSystem,20.0, NULL);
    NSDictionary *attributesDictTarget = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          (id)underline, (id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName,
                                          colorRed, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                          colorRed, (id)kCTStrokeColorAttributeName,nil];

    CGColorRef colorBlack = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    CTFontRef sysUIDefaultFont = CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage(kCTFontUIFontMessage,20.0, NULL);
    NSDictionary *attributesDictDefault = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           colorBlack, (id)kCTStrokeColorAttributeName,nil];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attMString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributesDictDefault];

    NSAttributedString *stringToDraw = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tarGetString
                                                                       attributes:attributesDictTarget];

    [attMString appendAttributedString:stringToDraw];

    NSAttributedString *stringRest = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str
                                                                     attributes:attributesDictDefault];

    [attMString appendAttributedString:stringRest];

    NSLog(@"check %@", [attMString string]);

    return (attMString);
}
}
```